# Random shut down when laptop is unplugged Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, lenovo, ideapad

I just shift from Windows OS to Ubuntu 18.04 and my LENOVO ideapad 310 is experiencing random shut down when it is unplugged from AC charger. Battery sometimes is at 80%, sometimes at 20%. Laptop is quite new and it didn't react like this when I was using Windows.
Battery and fan seems working properly.
Shut downs never occur when laptop is plugged.

I haven't find a solution in the web.

Thanks for your support

Comment: Did you check the kernel and system logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change or disable power saving settings. Setttings -> Power Management.
There is bound to be some hardware component that is reacting not as it should.